# JS returning value then returning "undefined"

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I'm fetching a value from a socket.io server and then passing it to the client in order to be displayed. One variable that I'm passing works fine, but the other one displays one value first before returning it as "undefined". I'm not really sure why this is, because both values show up in the client-side console without issue.

Here's the concerning bit of client-side JS:

```
  var socket = io();
  socket.on('broadcast',function(data) {
     document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = data.rating;
     document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = data.description;

     console.log(data);
     console.log(data.rating);
  });
```

...and here's the server.js file:

```
biasDetector.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
      var outputText = data.toString('utf8');
      var rating = (reliabilityResult['type']);
      console.log(outputText);
      console.log("Second check" + rating);
      io.sockets.emit('broadcast',{description: outputText}, {rating: rating});
    });
```

I check the value of `rating` several times throughout server.js, and it never comes up as undefined, which leads me to believe that it's a client-side JS issue as I'm getting the other value `description` without issue.

Thanks!

Comment: Try `io.sockets.emit('broadcast', { description: outputText, rating: rating })`

Comment: @ExplosionPills Yep, that worked! I knew it was something ridiculously simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attempting to send two separate objects with this:

```
io.sockets.emit('broadcast',{description: outputText}, {rating: rating});
```

But, then trying to read both properties from a single object on the receiving side of things with this:

```
socket.on('broadcast',function(data) {
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = data.rating;
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = data.description;
});
```

Change the server to put both properties on a single object:

```
io.sockets.emit('broadcast', {description: outputText, rating: rating});
```

so the sending side matches the reading side.